# get count of all rows specify different where clause

Tags: mysql, database

I have a simple table that have a column `id`. This column is not primary key(PK). The value of the id can be between 1 to 10. I want to write a query that gives me the count of all number in a single table like following:

```
one   two three four ............
 5     8    9     15 ...........
```

I know I can write a query like this `select count(*) from table where id = 1`. But this returns me the single number count means `id =1`. I need to write a query of all of the numbers between 1 to 10 in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Pivoting

Something along the lines of:

```
select 
count(case when id= 1 then 1 end) One,
count(case when id= 2 then 1 end) Two,
count(case when id= 3 then 1 end) Three,
count(case when id= 4 then 1 end) Four,
count(case when id= 5 then 1 end) Five,
count(case when id= 6 then 1 end) Six,
count(case when id= 7 then 1 end) Seven,
count(case when id= 8 then 1 end) Eight,
count(case when id= 9 then 1 end) Nine,
count(case when id= 10 then 1 end) Ten
from data;
```

Results:

```
ONE TWO  THREE  FOUR    FIVE    SIX SEVEN   EIGHT   NINE    TEN
4   1      0      0       0       0    0      0        0    1
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eee1/3)

### Without Pivoting

You could use the following:

```
select id, count(*) as Count from data group by id;
```

The results will be displayed as:

```
id, count
1            5 
2            8
3            9
4            15
```

Comment: This would return all possible rows in the database, to filter it further, you could use something like this: 
'select id, count(*) as Count from data where id between 1 and 10 group by id;'

Comment: Your "fix" seems unecessary based on the op question "The value of the id can be between 1 to 10". If all 'id's are between 1 and 10 the condition is not needed.

Comment: I understand and as stated in the comment, this is purely a "filter" - not a "fix", I am not taking anything away from your answer, however, I am basing the code on "defensive coding practices", so although it is a matter of opinion, I personally prefer "prevension is better than cure".

Comment: ok, seems reasonable given that if suddenly incorrect data was entered the `where` clause would handle it... then again, the `With Pivoting` solution takes care of that simply because the cases are from 1 to 10. Additionally, if the requirement was 1 to infinity, a different dynamic solution would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This query might be useful

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY [column_id] 
HAVING id >= 1 && id <= 10
```

Comment: As is, `column_id` not visible to distinguish for which `ID` you have the `count`.  Maybe try: `SELECT [column_id], COUNT(*) ...`